# Object-like macro definition starting with a left paren

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, standards, c11

Preemptive Note: I am aware that `lparen` is defined to be "a `(` character not immediately preceded by `white-space`" and that this could be trivially worked around by changing the macro definition to `#define FOO (`. This is a pedantic question from the point of view of someone implementing a **C** preprocessor.

```
#define FOO(
int main FOO) {
    return 0;
}
```

My reading of the C11 standard leaves me under the impression that this is a valid program in which an object-like macro named `FOO` is defined with a replacement list consisting of a single `(` preprocessing token.

**6.10.3p9:**

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>   `# define identifier replacement-list new-line` defines an object-like macro

**6.10.3p10:**

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `# define identifier lparen identifier-list_opt ) replacement-list new-line`
>
> `# define identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line`
>
> `# define identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line`
>
> defines a function-like macro

Both clang 3.5 and gcc 4.9 reject this program, apparently considering `FOO` to be an ill-formed function-like macro definition. Have I missed an explicit rule in the standard somewhere that a match on the `lparen` term forces the macro definition to be treated as a function-like macro, or is this a bug in both compilers? I would expect this to be parsed as an object-like macro given that it does not match the grammar given for a function-like macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

§ 6.10.3 Macro replacement

3. There shall be white-space between the identifier and the replacement list in the definition of an object-like macro.